# Iterating over hash.keys and running through through case/when

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
{:category => 1}.keys.each do |n|
    case n
    when 'category'
        puts 'success'
    else
        puts "failure: #{n}"
    end
end
```

This ends with "failure: category", and I cannot for the life of me see why, so I'm reasonably sure that I'm doing something enormously stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `when 'category'` with `when :category`

Comment: Because it's a symbol and not a string, d'oh. Knew it was something stupid, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You try to compare `'category'` string and `:category` symbol - they are different:

```
'category' === :category
# => false
```

This should work:

```
{:category => 1}.keys.each do |n|
  case n
  when :category
    puts 'success'
  else
    puts "failure: #{n}"
  end
end
```